# Generate variables with a multiple parameter function (with permutations of the parameter values)

Tags: r, function, loops

I'm using function which has 3 components, alpha beta and switchpoint. I need to adjust these 3 components to create multiple permutations of those parameters. Here is some code to demonstrate a simple example where the parameters have already been given specific values

```
a <- 2 # alpha
b <- 2 # beta 
sp <- 50 # Switch Point 

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(X1 = seq(0,200,by=10), X2 = sample(0:200,21 ))
```

This is the formula, for the above parameter values

```
    attach(df)

df$X1_a2_b2_sp50 <- ((X1/(((-(-(sp^a)*a-(sp^a)))/(a*b-b))^(1/a)))^a)/(((X1/(((-(-(sp^a)*a-(sp^a)))/(a*b-b))^(1/a)))^a)+ b)

> df
    X1  X2 X1_a2_b2_sp50
1    0 158    0.00000000
2   10 178    0.01315789
3   20  13    0.05063291
4   30 194    0.10714286
5   40 169    0.17582418
6   50  49    0.25000000
7   60 117    0.32432432
8   70  42    0.39516129
9   80 198    0.46043165
.
etc
```

As you can see the from the new variable it has the name starting with X1 to signify the original variable name, then it has a2 which indicates the alpha level, and the same for b=2 and sp=50. I need to create multiple transformations changing the values a, b, sp. Here below is a list of the values I need to change for each parameter. I also need to do this for multiple variables, doing the same for X2.

```
a_list <- c(2 , 3 , 4)
b_list <- c( 2, 5) 
sp_list <- c(50, 100, 150, 200)
var_list <- c("X1", "X2")
```

The result for X1 would be creating 24 variables =   3 (a) x 2 (b) x 4 (sp)

```
# For X1, there should be these variables

df$X1_a2_b2_sp50
df$X1_a2_b2_sp100
df$X1_a2_b2_sp150
df$X1_a2_b2_sp200
df$X1_a2_b5_sp50
df$X1_a2_b5_sp100
df$X1_a2_b5_sp150
df$X1_a2_b5_sp200
df$X1_a3_b2_sp50
df$X1_a3_b2_sp100
df$X1_a3_b2_sp150
df$X1_a3_b2_sp200
df$X1_a3_b5_sp50
df$X1_a3_b5_sp100
df$X1_a3_b5_sp150
df$X1_a3_b5_sp200
df$X1_a4_b2_sp50
df$X1_a4_b2_sp100
df$X1_a4_b2_sp150
df$X1_a4_b2_sp200
df$X1_a4_b5_sp50
df$X1_a4_b5_sp100
df$X1_a4_b5_sp150
df$X1_a4_b5_sp200
```

Then the same for X2. The way i'm going about this is to use a for loop (for each parameter) and use assign to create the variable name. I was just wondering if there an easier way to do so simplify this? Can this be done any other way in R? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. If there are any packages or methods to recommend i can look into that. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is:.

1. first build a data frame with all possible combinations of a_list, b_list and sp_list using `tidyr::expand_grid`
2. construct a named list of parametrized function calls from this df
3. have `dplyr` run all of those functions across your chosen variables using `mutate(across())`

I hope this gets you where you want :)

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

a_list <- c(2 , 3 , 4)
b_list <- c( 2, 5)
sp_list <- c(50, 100, 150, 200)
var_list <- c("X1", "X2")

param_df <-  expand_grid(
    a = a_list,
    b = b_list,
    sp = sp_list
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    colname = paste0("a",a,"_b",b,"_sp",sp)
  )

my_fun <- function(a, b, sp, ...) {
  function(vec){
    ((vec/(((-(-(sp^a)*a-(sp^a)))/(a*b-b))^(1/a)))^a)/(((vec/(((-(-(sp^a)*a-(sp^a)))/(a*b-b))^(1/a)))^a)+ b)
  }
}

funs_ls <- param_df %>%
  pmap(my_fun) %>%
  setNames(param_df$colname)

result <- df %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      .cols = all_of(var_list),
      funs_ls
    )
  )
```

Comment: thanks that is brilliant. I managed to do it in end with a loop, but i really like the way you used the param_df above. I can see the flexibility of your approach. Many thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

@alex, here's just to share the way i did it. I learnt how to create a function too to make that bit easier. I don't have a great understanding of R such as dplr, so did it a more simple way.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(X1 = seq(0,200,by=10), X2 = sample(0:200,21 )) 

a_list <- c(2 , 3 , 4)
b_list <- c( 2, 5)
sp_list <- c(50, 100, 150, 200)
var_list <- c("X1", "X2")

attach(df)

func_dr <- function(x, a, b, sp) 
{  ((x/(((-(-(sp^a)*a-(sp^a)))/(a*b-b))^(1/a)))^a)/(((x/(((-(-(sp^a)*a-(sp^a)))/(a*b-b))^(1/a)))^a)+ b) }

container <- numeric()

for (i in 1:length(var_list)) {
  for (j in 1:length(a_list)) {
    for (k in 1:length(b_list)) {
      for (l in 1:length(sp_list)) {
    
        result <- func_dr(eval(parse(text = var_list[i])), a_list[j], b_list[k], sp_list[l]  )
        container <- cbind(container, result)
        colnames(container)[ncol(container)] <- paste(var_list[i], 
                                                      paste("a", a_list[j], sep = ""), 
                                                      paste("b", b_list[k], sep = ""), 
                                                      paste("sp", sp_list[l], sep = ""), 
                                                      sep = "_")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This probably not a good way to write in R, but I'm still learning. Thanks